# Accessing Amazon Web Services SQS Queue in Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I currently have an Amazon Web Services SQS queue which I use throughout my php project. I am trying to now write a service in Python which adds items to the SQS queue. However I cannot get a connection to my existing queue. The code I have is:

```
    import boto.sqs
    from boto.sqs.message import Message

    conn = boto.sqs.connect_to_region('us-west-2', aws_access_key_id='my key', aws_secret_access_key='my secret key')
    print(conn.get_all_queues())
```

When I run the above code I get an empty array back instead of my current queue. Any ideas why this is happening or how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: My guess is it is a permissions issue. Try creating a queue from boto. `conn.create_queue('newQueue')` and see if that one shows up when you do `get_all_queues()`. You might have to adjust the permission of the queue to see the one you (probably) created in the console

Comment: Ya I tried that and it worked and I don't think it is a permissions problem since I am using the same credentials as my php script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the object directly as long as you have the URL and a SQSConnection object.

```
q = Queue(connection, url)
```